# Back Date publication

Tags: research-process, journals, paper-submission

I finished a research paper 2 years ago, and it was related to the covid pandemic. I didn't try to publish it because my father passed away and I stopped research work for a long time. Is it possible to do backdate publication for that paper?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Seems likely to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question - what's the problem you're trying to solve with this solution? (echoing Azor Ahai)

Comment: No, you submit now and see how it goes.

Answer (score 8):

**No**

The journal provides the date received, the date revised, and the date published. Since your paper was not received two years ago, the journal cannot say it was.